# When I press F11 I get this error: Error : could not start the command : bibtex "test"

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I'm using TexMaker and I'm having trouble with natbib. When I press F11 I get the following error: Error: could not start the command: bibtex "test" (where "test" is the name of the file).

I stopped using LaTeX for some time. I used to be able to compile the bibliography with no problems. Now that I got back to it, I'm having this problem. I already got the new version of TexMaker, and that doesn't help.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}



\usepackage[round]{natbib}


\title{Title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Hello \citep{asher2009}

\bibliographystyle{newapa}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have bibtex installed, do you have tex installed? That's a system level error meaning the command isn't found so not related to your specific document.

Comment: What is your operating system?  If you go to a command line and type `bibtex --version`, what do you get?

Comment: I have win 10, and after typing what you told me in the command line I get that I have the MiKTeX-BibTeX 4.1 (MiKTeX 23.12)

Comment: I'm fairly sure I have bibtex and tex installed. A few months I was able to get a proper bibliography with no trouble.